# Would this be considered dependency injection?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

Would this be considered dependency injection, or delegation or object collaboration?

https://gist.github.com/3428071

Comment: The page description says "dependency injection in php/codeigniter."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ors in your question make it sound like those three things are mutually exclusive.

This is a form of dependency injection, albeit a non-conventional form of it. In the end, you are injecting Logger_model into User_model, so it is injection of a dependency. It is also true to say that Logger_model is a collaborator in this instance. And it is also true that User_model delegates logging to Logging_model.

So, basically, it's all of the above.

Comment: Thank you. I sat back and thought about the interaction of the classes some more and came to the same conclusion.  However since you say this is a non-conventional form of it, would say using a Strategy Pattern where the User class instantiates the Logger depending on the action taken?  What would be a more conventional form of DI?

Comment: @AndreDublin Have a read of this: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321158/A-beginners-guide-to-Dependency-Injection